# Visual Studio Code, возможна ли одновременная отладка серверного и клиентского JS?

Tags: javascript, отладка, visual-studio-code

В VS Code "из коробки" есть возможность отлаживать запущенный на Node.js код, с плагином "Debugger for Chrome" есть возможность отлаживать клиентский JS. Вопрос есть ли возможность отлаживать серверный и клиентский JS одновременно?

Comment: Через добавление в рабочее пространство. Вот видео, в котором есть все что вам нужно, и еще несколько полезных нововведений https://youtu.be/xYyPAUukFfg?t=761

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать запустить 2 экземпляра VS Code:
В одном открыть backend и отлаживать стандартными средствами, в другом открыть frontend и использовать плагин. А вообще почитайте документацию к плагину, надо копать именно туда.